# Getting an NZEC error in SPOJ for this code

Tags: java

Getting an `NZEC runtime error in SPOJ` for the `PRIME1` problem with this solution.
Any insights on what I did wrong?

**The solution runs and gives output in netbeans and command prompt though.**

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main2
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {   

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        int num = s.nextInt();
        int[] m = new int[num];
        int[] n = new int[num];

        for(int z=0;z<num;z++)
        {
         m[z] = s.nextInt();
         n[z] = s.nextInt();
        }

        for(int z = 0 ; z<num ; z++)
        {
            boolean[] x = new boolean[n[z]+1];
            for(int i = 2 ; i<=n[z]; i++)
                x[i] = true;

            for(int i = 2 ; i*i<=n[z]; i++)
            {
                if(x[i])
                    for(int j=i;i*j<=n[z];j++)
                        x[i*j]=false;
            }

            for(int i = m[z] ; i <= n[z] ; i++)
            {
                if(x[i]==true)
                    System.out.println(i);
            }

        System.out.println();

        }
    }
}
```

Please guide me the correct way to achieve my objective.

Answer (score 1):

About NZEC error :

 NZEC stands for Non Zero Exit Code. In Java this error is generated if an exception is thrown.
Always try to implement the following format in Java to prevent NZEC error :

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
       try{
           //Your Solve
        }catch(Exception e){
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may wrap your code in 
`try { /* code */ } catch (Throwable trh) { return; }` in case your program throws any exception. Another cause of this problem might be the fact that your program exceeds time limit but somehow you are getting NZEC instead of TLE (mainly because you are using Scanner which is slow). I have read that that it might be a SPOJ bug.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should wrap your code inside try-catch block to avoid nzec(runtime error) but in your case the error is because of the class name. Class name should be Main instead of Main2

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {   

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        int num = s.nextInt();
        int[] m = new int[num];
        int[] n = new int[num];

        for(int z=0;z<num;z++)
        {
         m[z] = s.nextInt();
         n[z] = s.nextInt();
        }

        for(int z = 0 ; z<num ; z++)
        {
            boolean[] x = new boolean[n[z]+1];
            for(int i = 2 ; i<=n[z]; i++)
                x[i] = true;

            for(int i = 2 ; i*i<=n[z]; i++)
            {
                if(x[i])
                    for(int j=i;i*j<=n[z];j++)
                        x[i*j]=false;
            }

            for(int i = m[z] ; i <= n[z] ; i++)
            {
                if(x[i]==true)
                    System.out.println(i);
            }

        System.out.println();

        }
    }
}
```