# NZEC Prime number Generation SPOJ- http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/

Tags: java

I am beginner at coding. I am getting NZEC error on submission of my code for prime number genertaion to spoj. But the code is working perfectly fine in my desktop. Kindly help me. This is what i have coded.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.Math.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        int testcase;
        int lower_limit,upper_limit;
        int i,j,k;
        boolean[] a= new boolean[100001];
        Arrays.fill(a, Boolean.TRUE);
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        testcase= sc1.nextInt();
        for(;testcase>0;testcase--)
        {
            lower_limit= sc1.nextInt();
            upper_limit= sc1.nextInt();
            for(i = 2;i<sqrt(upper_limit);i++)
            {
                if(a[i]=true)
                {
                    for(j=i;j<=upper_limit;j=j+i)
                    {
                    a[j]=false;
                    }
                }
            }
                for(i=lower_limit;i<upper_limit;i++)
                {
                    if(a[i]==true)
                    {
                        System.out.println(i);
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried catching your exceptions as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571469/getting-an-nzec-error-in-spoj-for-this-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array goes out of index for large values of m and n. Try this sample test case on your system where m = 999900000 and n = 1000000000. You can't store these large values as the index of the array. Even m or n = 10^8 will go out of bound index for an array.